# SQLite console for in Windows IoT

Tags: sqlite, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I am troubleshooting an SQLite database on Windows IoT and access to a command prompt console to query the database would be great. There appears to be one for Windows PC, but is there a console I can install on Windows IoT?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Currently, there seems no official SQLite database command prompt supported for Windows iot core.

But you can build the source by yourself like this:

**1. Clone the [sqlite soure](https://github.com/alex85k/sqlite3-cmake)(here use version 3.12.1).**

[image]

**2. Use [CMake](https://cmake.org/download/) and enter source code and build path, for example, "C:\sqlite3-cmake-master".**

[image]

**3. Configure compiler for ARM.**

[image]

**4. Generate the Visual Studio solution.**

[image]

**5. Open the solution.**

[image]

**6. In Visual Studio, build solution.**

[image]

**7. After build successfully, you can get sqlite3.exe at this path:**

[image]

**8. Copy this sqlite3.exe to Windows iot core device. Then you can use the command prompt console.**

[image]